# VBA Auto Key In Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 main sheets at play here: 
S1 &
S2

S1 is a supply allocation form that has loads of past records and has a date cell which I can change. S2 is basically just where i would manually copy and paste my allocation of supply into. It is a long page filled with dates at the top which I have to manually check for in order to paste the supply allocation at the right date slot.

How can I have it so that the VBA checks for the date I set at S1 on a row of dates in S2. Then, copy and pasted my column of order(from S1) one cell below the date matched in S2?

Comment: Look at find and copy in the VBA help files.  This will explain, or record it?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav The thing is, most of what I found allows to finding the date and copying data already existing in the grand table of dates. What I need is the reverse. Finding a date in the grand table then pasting onto it. Any ideas?